# Spring LDAP Error Changing Distinguished Name

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, spring-ldap

I'm having trouble finding the proper way to move a person in Active Directory between organizational units with Spring LDAP.

I am using Spring LDAP 2.0.4.RELEASE. I have tried four different ways to set the `distinguishedName` on the person object that I am trying to move, and I get an LDAP error each way.

**1)** Setting `distinguishedName` as a `String`, including the `dc` portion.

```
final Name currentDn = LdapNameBuilder.newInstance("CN=Some Person,OU=Old,OU=Domain Users").build();
final String newDn = "CN=Some Person,OU=New,OU=Domain Users,dc=my,dc=domain";

final Attribute attributeChange = new BasicAttribute("distinguishedName", newDn);
final ModificationItem modificationItem = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, attributeChange);
ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes(currentDn, new ModificationItem[]{modificationItem});
```

This gives me the following error:

> javax.naming.directory.InvalidAttributeValueException: [LDAP: error code 19 - 000020B1: AtrErr: DSID-030F052C, #1:
>       0: 000020B1: DSID-030F052C, problem 1005 (CONSTRAINT_ATT_TYPE), data 0, Att 31 (distinguishedName)
>    ]; remaining name 'CN=Some Person,OU=Old,OU=Domain Users'

**2)** Setting `distinguishedName` as a `String`, *without* the `dc` portion.

```
final Name currentDn = LdapNameBuilder.newInstance("CN=Some Person,OU=Old,OU=Domain Users").build();
//the line below is the only line changed from (1)
final String newDn = "CN=Some Person,OU=New,OU=Domain Users"; 

final Attribute attributeChange = new BasicAttribute("distinguishedName", newDn);
final ModificationItem modificationItem = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, attributeChange);
ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes(currentDn, new ModificationItem[]{modificationItem});
```

This gives me a different error:

> org.springframework.ldap.UncategorizedLdapException: Uncategorized exception occured during LDAP processing; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 80 - 00002089: UpdErr: DSID-031B0D38, problem 5012 (DIR_ERROR), data 5
>    ]; remaining name 'CN=Some Person,OU=Old,OU=Domain Users'

**3)** Setting `distinguishedName` as a `LdapName`, including the `dc` portion.

```
final Name currentDn = LdapNameBuilder.newInstance("CN=Some Person,OU=Old,OU=Domain Users").build();
final Name newDn = LdapNameBuilder.newInstance("CN=Some Person,OU=New,OU=Domain Users,dc=my,dc=domain").build();

final Attribute attributeChange = new BasicAttribute("distinguishedName", newDn);
final ModificationItem modificationItem = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, attributeChange);
ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes(currentDn, new ModificationItem[]{modificationItem});
```

This gives me the same error as (1).

**4)** Setting `distinguishedName` as a `LdapName`, *without* the `dc` portion.

```
final Name currentDn = LdapNameBuilder.newInstance("CN=Some Person,OU=Old,OU=Domain Users").build();
final Name newDn = LdapNameBuilder.newInstance("CN=Some Person,OU=New,OU=Domain Users").build();

final Attribute attributeChange = new BasicAttribute("distinguishedName", newDn);
final ModificationItem modificationItem = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, attributeChange);
ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes(currentDn, new ModificationItem[]{modificationItem});
```

This gives me the same error as (1) as well.

What am I missing? Is this not the proper way to change the `distinguishedName` on an Active Directory person object with Spring LDAP? The error messages are not very helpful at all.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you cannot change the `distinguishedName` attribute with a modify operation. The proper way to do this with Spring LDAP is using the [`LdapTemplate.rename`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/core/LdapTemplate.html#rename-javax.naming.Name-javax.naming.Name-) method. You can pass in the `oldDn` and `newDn` as `String` objects or `Name` objects.

```
final Name oldDn = LdapNameBuilder.newInstance("CN=Some Person,OU=Old,OU=Domain Users").build();
final Name newDn = LdapNameBuilder.newInstance("CN=Some Person,OU=New,OU=Domain Users").build();

ldapTemplate.rename(oldDn, newDn);
```

Comment: this is because DN is not an attribute. The related LDAP operation/request is MODRDN and not a plain MODIFY